# Error in double pointer to array parameter

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

```
int main (void)
{
    int** arr = new int*[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) arr[i] = new int[4] {1, 0, 0, 1};

    const int* p = &(arr[0][0]);

    TFigure* test = new TFigure(arr, 4, 4);
    test->resolve();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) delete[] arr[i];
    delete[] arr;

    return 0;
}
```

where constructor declaration is
    line 57:

```
TFigure(int **ia, int n, int m)
    N = n;
    M =m;

    landscape = new int*[n];
    puddles = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        landscape[i] = new int[m];
        puddles[i] = new int[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            landscape[i][j] = *ia[i][j];
        }


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 0; j++)
            if (i == 0 || i == N || j == 0 || j == M)
                puddles[i][j] = 0;
            else
                puddles[i][j] = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    std::cout << puddles[i][j] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    std::cout << landscape[i][j] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
    }


};
```

but I have an error

> 57:43: error: invalid type argument of unary `«*»` (have `«int»`)

I don't understand what causes this.

Comment: Which line is line 57?

Comment: Your code should work. Please show the whole definition of `TFigure`

Comment: agree with Andy Prowl above. btw, don't forget to `delete test;` as well.

Comment: What is that `int* p` used for? That variable doesn't make sense given that `arr` is a ragged (or jagged) array. Why is that declaration even there? You aren't using `p` in the code shown. And finally, what is line 57?

Comment: [Please don’t use pointers here](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/#1)

Comment: p is remains since last changes. i removed it and nothing changes. 57 line is constructor declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
landscape[i][j] = *ia[i][j];
```

`ia[i][j]` gives you an `int` which you then try to dereference. It seems like you really just want:

```
landscape[i][j] = ia[i][j];
```

I'm not sure if this was a mistake when copy and pasting or not, but your constructor definition is missing an opening `{`.

```
TFigure(int **ia, int n, int m) {
//                         Here ^
```